# Android, How do I know if the application has closed

Tags: android

I need to know when the user close the App, not when the user press on the "home" button, but when the user close the App at the "recent applications menu".
At those two cases the App go to the onPause method. Is there any way to tell them apart?
I`m asking because, I want to delete the user from my database on one situation, and not at the other.

Comment: You may never know it! `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called when process is killed!

Comment: [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) "Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going into the background, but has not (yet) been killed" in other words, onPause() is also called even when the application isn't "closed" at all, by any means.

Answer (score 1):

you can try combining multiple callbacks from the activity lifecycle.

[`onUserLeaveHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()) can be realy usefull to get know if the activity is in background or foreground

[`isFinishing()`](http://%20isFinishing()): can bu used to know if the activity is been closed by a `finish()` call or if is the system shutting down the activity to free resources

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a Service for that, in this service override  onTrimMemory method

```
@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    switch (level) {
        case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN:
               //app was closed        
            break;
    }

}
```

check more about services

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) can help you. It need to test.

Example:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        lifecycleListener = new ActivityLifecycleListener();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(lifecycleListener);
    }

    public class ActivityLifecycleListener implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        }
    }
}
```